# What kind of regression to use with heavily skewed data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, link-function

I have data with an explanatory variable $X$ (I think I can treat this as  continuous, as scores 1-100 on a certain test) and a response variable $Y$ (continuous variable, never lower than 0). Both are NOT normally distributed ($X$ is close to, $Y$ is not at all).

I wanted to do a regression, using `glm()` in R. However, I cannot decide what family/link function to use.

I found that it does not really matter that my $X$ is not normally distributed. However, it does that my $Y$ is not. There are many 0 observations, i.e. skewed right. Doing a log transformation of this variable makes it more difficult to interpret the results, so I found that using `family = Gamma` would be appropriate. However, I do not know / understand how to choose a link function. Should it be inverse, log or identity? How can I choose?

Comment: The link function describes the relationship between the predictor and the response variable, so a good choice will really depend on the nature of the variables. Can you describe $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: X is a score of a soccer player on a certain cognitive test, ranging from 0-100. Y is a continuous variable, his market value.

Comment: I thought using the link = log was the best option, but I got an error. I thought this was because log(0) is not possible, so I gave the players with a market value of 0 a 'symbolical' value of 1 for the glm to be able to do the math with these players as well. This also did not work. What should I do?

Comment: Also, X is in fact normally distributed.

Comment: Linear regression assumes *conditional* normality of $Y$, not marginal. That means it's not relevant how $Y$ itself is distributed, only how it's distributed conditional on the values of $X$. How do the residuals diagnostic plots look like? If a Gamma-distribution does not work, have a look at the GAMLSS package.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Ah, I had no clue do it seems. How do I check for that?

Comment: I'd check the assumptions by looking at the residual diagnostic plots.

Comment: Problem is that you have to first be able to run a regression, right?

Comment: The identity link function would cause a linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$: an increase of one unit on cognitive score leads to a constant increase in market value. This is unlikely as market value is relatively open ended.
The log sounds like an appropriate choice. You say it didn't work; what exactly went wrong?

Comment: @Ous ; I got an error concerning the glm fit, stating that there were NAs / Inf values in 'x', whatever that means. Any idea?

Comment: @Ous that is, if I change the 0 values to 1 or 10, because when I left them 0, I got a wrning stating that 'non-positive values' were not allowed for the gamma family.

Comment: Missing values of various flavours often need to be excluded explicitly in R calls. How to do that is off-topic here: please read advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions. But having zeros in the response is not a problem with a log link, as a log link does not mean that your GLM software is trying to transform your response by taking logarithms. The assumption is that the mean is positive conditionally on your predictors.

Comment: you should look at regression models with a zero inflated continuous response (a number of posts already on site discuss zero-inflated gamma or similar models)

Comment: @Pannie I could reproduce the fact that a glm with a Gamma link function does not run if the dependent variable contains 0s, but I have no issue if I replace those 0s by positive values. Are these 0s meaningful in your model? If they have an explanation distinct from your predictors (e.g. "players who have never signed a contract yet have 0 value on the market by default") you may consider dropping them entirely.

Comment: @Ous very true, I am considering that indeed. Thank you very much!